# How to return all matches from a list in MongoDB via Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I'm looking to provide a list of potential matches to a Node-based Mongo query, and can't seem to find existing examples of how it is done.

A simplified example of the way I am getting results back for *single* strings is as follows:

```
myCollection.find({"index" : index}).toArray(function (err, items) {
    if (items && items.length > 0){
        res.status(200).send(items);
    }
    else {
        res.status(404).send("NOT FOUND");
    }
});
```

How can I modify this so that I can pass in a list of indexes, instead of a single value, and have all fully matching results returned?

EDIT: I don't believe this question is a complete duplicate - the other question deals with returning a single response, whereas I need *all* matches in that list

Comment: May be you are looking for [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator ?

Comment: That’s the one, thanks. If you put that as an answer I will accept it. Tar.